# Consuming REST service in IPhone

Tags: iphone

So far I have been working on Iphone applications which use SOAP service to interact with web. I have just decided to use **REST** service in my next IPhone application. Though looking here and there I may find a solution. But I just wanted to know all about using REST service in IPhone SDK in one go.
Does anyone have a fair idea of consuming **REST** service in Iphone development? What approach might prove to be the best? Kindly provide with the complete implementation to using the same.

Stone

Comment: I used http://restkit.org/. Maybe it fits your needs.

Comment: i see your game set for REST services, but seriously, stick with SOAP -> use WSDL2OBJC (found on google code) to do all the hard work for you. in the mean time, if your adament, use restkit.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the ASIHTTPRequest library found [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Its really straight forward and support just about all the HTTP operation such as POST, PUT, GET etc.

Answer (score 1):

http://restkit.org/

And

http://iphoneonrails.com/

Are good libraries to play with RESTful webservices